# string pattern matching using python

Tags: python, string

I am working on python and bio sequences.
I have a sequence.

```
seq1 = \
...        """ atgaaatttatcattgaacgtgagcatctgctaaaaccactgcaacaggtcagtagcccg
...        ctgggtggacgccctacgttgcctattttgggtaacttgttgctgcaagtcacggaaggc
...        tctttgcggctgaccggtaccgacttggagatggagatggtggcttgtgttgccttgtct
...        cagtcccatgagccgggtgctaccacagtacccgcacggaagttttttgatatctggcgt
...        ggtttacccgaaggggcggaaattacggtagcgttggatggtgatcgcctgctagtgcgc
...        tctggtcgcagccgtttctcgctgtctaccttgcctgcgattgacttccctaatctggat
...        gactggcagagtgaggttgaattcactttaccgcaggctacgttaaagcgtctgattgag
...        tccactcagttttcgatggcccatcaggatgtccgttattatttgaacggcatgctgttt
...        gagaccgaaggcgaagagttacgtactgtggcgaccgatgggcatcgcttggctgtatgc
...        tcaatgcctattggccagacgttaccctcacattcggtgatcgtgccgcgtaaaggtgtg
...        atggagctggttcggttgctggatggtggtgatacccccttgcggctgcaaattggcagt
...        aataatattcgtgctcatgtgggcgattttattttcacatctaagctggttgatggccgt
...        ttcccggattatcgccgcgtattgccgaagaatcctgataaaatgctggaagccggttgc
...        gatttactgaaacaggcattttcgcgtgcggcaattctgtcaaatgagaagttccgtggt
...        gttcggctctatgtcagccacaatcaactcaaaatcactgctaataatcctgaacaggaa
...        gaagcagaagagatcctcgatgttagctacgaggggacagaaatggagatcggtttcaac
...        gtcagctatgtgcttgatgtgctaaatgcactgaagtgcgaagatgtgcgcctgttattg
...        actgactctgtatccagtgtgcagattgaagacagcgccagccaagctgcagcctatgtc
...        gtcatgccaatgcgtttgtag"""

seq2 = \
...        """ accgtagcatctgctaaaaccagtacgcccg
...        ctgggtggacgatgcaacttgttgctgcaagtcacggaaggc
...        tctttgcggctgaccggtaccgacttggagatggagatggtggcttgtgttgccttgtct
...        cagtcccatgagccgggtgctaccacagtacccgcacggaagttttttgatatctggcgt
...        ggtttacccgaaggggcggaaattacggtagcgttggatggtgcatgatcgcctgctagtgcgc
...        tctggtcgcagccgtttctcgctgtctaccttgcctgcgattgacttccctaatctggat
...        gactggcagagtgaggttgaattcactttaccgcaggctacgttaaagcgtctgattgag
...        tccactcagttttcgatgctatttatgtccgttattatttgaacggcatgctgttt
...        gagaccgaaggcgaagagttacgtactgtggcgaccgatgggcatcgcttggctgtatgc
...        tcaatgcctattggccaggctaattcggtgatcgtgccgcgtaaaggtgtg
...        atggagctggttcggttgctggatggtggtgatacccccggcccctgcaaattggcagt
...        aataatattcgtgctcatgtgggcgattttattttcacatctaagctggttgatggccgt
...        ttcccggattatcgccgcgtattgccgaagaatcctgataaaatgctggaagccggttgc
...        gtcatgccaatgcgtttgtag"""
```

I want to find out that how many strings in seq1 and seq2 are same and their respective positions. 
This is not only pattern matching but getting the positions as well. 
can anyone tell me how can i do the same using python?

Comment: "How many strings in seq1 and seq2 are the same" -- Can you be more specific?  Is there any constraint on how long a "string" is, or where it starts?

Comment: Don't start with "using Python".  Start with "at all", because you need to have an algorithm for this first.

Comment: Also, is there any significance in the linebreaks, or are they there just to make it easier to read the lines (e.g., should they be stripped out when "matching"?

Comment: @mgilson : no. from the given sequences, I have to search and see how many strings are matching with another sequences, and then I have to write the matching strings and their positions

Comment: linebreaks are just to make it easier to read

Comment: @sam, so since `a` is in both strings, you need to know every position of `a` in both strings?

Comment: For an algorithm, start analyzing this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring and see if that will sorta fit your problem.  E.g. try not discarding the not-longest substrings, and think about how you will deal with overlapping matches.

Comment: I still do not understand, what you expect: for the given example, please provide the first 3 results.

Comment: for example occurance of 'acc' in both sequences and their position. like this way, it will first start with one alphabate search and so on.

Comment: so first you will loop through all 1 element strings in seq1 and check for their existence in seq2, then for all 2 element strings, ... and once that is done, you start with seq2 and check for matches in seq1? How long is the longes sequence?

Comment: longest will be the length of sequence

Comment: Ok, last try: PLEASE provide a full example in full sentence including the output and output format, otherwise this will be just guessing, edit your post!!!

Answer (score 1):

The indexer function will return all posistions as a list

```
def indexer(s, sub):
    positions=[]
    pos=0
    while True:
        pos=s.find(sub,pos+1)
        if pos==-1:
            return positions
        else:
            positions.append(pos)
```

The matcher function will return a dict. Each key in the the dict is a sequences that is available in both a and b, the respective dict value is 2 item tuple that contains all matching positions for a and all matching positions for b:

```
def matcher(a,b):
    sequences=set()
    for l in range(1,len(a)):
        for pos in range(len(a)):
            sequences.add(a[pos:pos+l])
    for l in range(1,len(b)):
        for pos in range(len(b)):
            sequences.add(b[pos:pos+l]) 
    matches={}
    for seq in sequences:
        matches_a=indexer(a,seq)
        matches_b=indexer(b,seq)
        if result_a and result_b:
            matches[seq]=(matches_a,matches_b)
    return matches
```

This example should work:

```
print matcher('asdfasdfa','asdfasasdfasdfasdfadfasdfdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `index`:

```
>>> seq.index(str)
1046
```

Note that it'll find you the position of first occurence. You could then try to find other occurences from slices.

**EDITED**

When there are several occurences, a loop like such could work:

```
test = seq1 + ""
try:
    while test:
        position = test.index(str_)
        positions.append(position + last_position)
        position += len(str_)
        last_position += position
        test = test[position:]
except ValueError:
    print positions
```

We make a copy of the `seq` string because we'll consume it. Then, we keep checking a position with the `index` method, storing it in `positions` and updating the string accordingly.

[PS] Bad, bad idea to call a variable `str`, you're overwriting a built-in...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#Python) can help you get started?

Comment: but string will not be fixed. i have to match all the string cases from both the available sequences and then I want to find the strings and occurances

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, what you mean with "all string cases from both the available sequences" Of any length?

Comment: I think he's looking for the longest common subsequence.